# Как передать в функцию переменную?

Tags: javascript, html, функции, переменные

Есть функция:

```
function UserPaga() {
        alert(number);
    }
```

Вот код который её вызывает :

`<div onClick='UserPaga();'></div>`

необходимо чтобы при нажатии не только функция запускалась, но и передавалась переменная `number`!
Как это сделать ?

Comment: Читать документацию по JavaScript..  Другого способа решения этой проблемы я не вижу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В функции пишется переменная, которая передаётся:

```
function UserPaga(number) {  alert(number); }
```

При вызове функции пишется значение передаваемой переменной:

```
UserPaga(999);
```

В итоге получается такой html код:

```
<script>
function UserPaga(number) {
    alert(number); // 999
}
</script>
<div onClick='UserPaga(999);'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо я так и думол только писал вот так :

<script>
function UserPaga(number) {
    alert(number); // 999
}
</script>
<div onClick='UserPaga(var number="999");'></div>

Answer (score 3):

```
<div onClick='UserPaga(999);'></div>

function UserPaga(number) {
    alert(number); // 999
}
```